# How do I trigger a Javascript function AFTER the page loads?

Tags: php, javascript, html, events, onload

** EDIT **

I'm afraid I wasn't in the right direction - the problem isn't what I asked about.
the Javascript works as it should, it's the PHP that doesn't show what I want it to
on the first "run" - and I'm stil not sure why.
Sorry for somewhat wasting your time...

**

I have a form that might or might not already contain data in its fields.
If a user reaches the form and he already has some data in the system,
his ID number, for instance, will appear in the ID field - and a JavaScript function running
onLoad will disable the input field and change its style:

```
<body onload="runFunction()">
```

the problem is that it seems to run before the PHP does its part,
and only if I refresh the page, the JS function does everything I want it to
(it disables and styles some other form fields that depend on a PHP condition).

Is there a way to have this JS function run AFTER the page was rendered?
I tried running this before closing the page:

```
<body>
...
...
<script>
runFunction();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but to no avail.

any ideas?
Thanks!

some of the relevant PHP code: [I removed id attributes to make reading easier]

```
<?php if ($h_phone != '' && $h_phone_pre != '') {  
echo "<td class=\"input\"><input type=\"text\" id=\"new_user_home_tel\" value=\"$h_phone\" size=\"8\" maxlength=\"7\" disabled=\"disabled\" /> -  
<select id=\"new_user_home_tel_pre\" disabled=\"disabled\">  
  <option value=\"$h_phone_pre\" selected=\"selected\"></option>";

     } else {

echo '<td class="input"><input type="text" id="new_user_home_tel" size="8" maxlength="7" /> -  
 <select id="new_user_home_tel_pre">  
   <option value=" " selected="selected"></option>';
    }?>  <option value="02">02</option>
     <option value="03">03</option>
     <option value="04">04</option>
     <option value="08">08</option>
     <option value="09">09</option>
</select> 
</td>
```

the Javascript code just changes the style if the field isn't empty and that works,
but the PHP works only after a refresh.

Comment: Do you have any separate <?php ?> code in the form area? If so, can we please see a sample of your form input, including the php?

Comment: @Fran - I added some PHP code, I hope it's understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid I wasn't in the right direction - the problem isn't what I asked about. the Javascript works as it should, it's the PHP that doesn't show what I want it to on the first "run" - and I'm stil not sure why. Sorry for somewhat wasting your time...

Answer (score 5):

Your Javascript does run after the page is loaded, the problem is elsewhere.

It must be that your server sends different HTML before and after refresh. I suggest that if you save the source of the page you get first time and compare it with the source you get after refresh. I bet you will spot the difference and that will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Does it repro if you save the HTML locally and open in from local machine?

Comment: I suggest you add a debug button that calls runFunction() on click and see what happens if you click that when you are sure the page is loaded.

There are no miracles, identical HTML should produce identical results.

Comment: One suggestion...  When I run into a JavaScript problem I try and step through the JavaScript code using a debug editor like Visual Studio.

Comment: @Dscoduc - this isn't a Javascript problem... so stepping through it is irrelevant here, I think.

Comment: Are you saying that the two HTMLs were not identical after all? That first one contains empty first option, and the second one has user phone there?

It seems then that the problem lies in the part of your PHP code that sets $h_phone and $h_phone_pre. I suspect some SQL problem.

Comment: it's definitely a PHP problem but the generated HTML was identical before and after refreshing, which is weird, I double-checked that...

Comment: Weird. I doubt we can help you w/o reproing the situation. :(

Answer (score 2):

JQuery does this.  Anything inside the following will execute once the page is rendered:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Call your function here
});
```

Comment: That jQuery code does exactly what his code does, there could be no difference.

The reason jQuery way is better is that it does not require changing HTML, nothing more.

Comment: I tried jQuery and it gives me Javascript errors, both the minified version, the uncompressed version, and even if I link directly to it.

Comment: @buti, that *is not* the same. jQuery will run that code when the document is ready but his onload handler will wait until all images have downloaded including banners.

Answer (score 0):

Try the "defer" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to output-buffer the page in PHP. That means everything generated goes into memory until the script finishes running and then it's all sent out at once.

Take a look at http://uk.php.net/ob_start

Answer (score 0):

the non JS library answer is:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
 /* do stuff */
}
</script>
```

However using a JS library like JQuery will take care of all those niggle cross browser bug/problems.

Your right to place your `<script>` blocks at the end of you body. This improves page load performance as the browser blocks when it hits a `<script>` block.

Comment: what's the difference between your suggestion and my calling the function from the JS I called at the document's <head>?
and the JS isn't so heavy - right now I don't mid if it takes a few more milliseconds to load...)

Comment: It wouldn't matter if you placed the window.onload at the beginning or the end of the body, as it will only get executed after the body finishes loading.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely hacky, but you could always put a 2x2 transparent image below your form and run the function using it's onLoad. I did a similar thing on a conditionally included file so there were no errors in the case that the file wasn't included.

Comment: I tried that... I added:
    <img src="images/test.gif" alt="test" onload="runFunction();"/>
instead of onload at the body tag, but sadly this dodn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you add your content to an output variable and than echo it at the end of the file. Ex:

```
...
$output .= '<body onload="runFunction();">';
while(...)
{
   $output .= '...';
}
$output .= '</body>';
...
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really late for this post, but the reason this isn't working is that PHP renders HTML and then you can't interact with it again (unless you can do some snazzy AJAX stuff). Point being that the JS works fine bc it is client side, PHP doesn't work bc it is server side. Hope that helps anyone else who comes here!